# h5py - Get Index of Specific Values

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have an .h5 file that is being read in python via the h5py library. Code to pull in the data is:

```
file = h5py.File('example.h5','r+')
data_file = file['data_1'] 
dates = data_file['Date']
```

I would like to get a list of the index values for a specific date. For example, The dates dataset has ~300 values (out of 10K) that are 20120304. Is there a way to get these index values without reading the entire dataset into memory? My end goal is to pull in all data where the dates row is equal to 20120304.

Comment: You can load a slice of the dataset into memory and test values, e.g. `arr = 
 dates[:300]`.  You can also access rows by number, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing.  But you can't test rows for specific values without loading them into memory.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to get the index values of all the dates I want so I can pull in data from other datasets with the corresponding index?

Comment: I would use `np.where` with a equality test in the desired column.

Comment: If `dates`  is 2d and you want to check values in 1st column, you load `dates[:,0]`